# Prove $(rs)^{t}=r^{t}s^{t}$ for a real number $t\gt 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, exponentiation

[This lecture note](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/F12/MAT_215_powers.pdf) proved $(rs)^{t}=r^{t}s^{t}$ for a real number $t\gt 0$ by using the following statement: $$\text{sup}(AB)=\text{sup}A\,\text{sup}B.$$ I found this specific step problematic

> For the property, if $r,s\gt 1$, then we can just use equation (1), noting that $\{(rs)^{a}:a\in\mathbb{Q}\,\text{and}\,a\le t\}=AB$, where $A=\{r^{a}:a\in\mathbb{Q}\,\text{and}\,a\le t\}$ and $B=\{s^{a}:a\in\mathbb{Q}\,\text{and}\,a\le t\}$.

because $AB$ is defined as $\{ab:a\in A,b\in B\}.$ In other words, there are some elements in $AB$ where their exponents do not match, thereby not satisfying the above beautiful representation $(rs)^{a}.$ In conclusion, my question is

**Is my hypothesis right, which means the above proof does not hold?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right: in fact,
$$
AB \ne \{(rs)^a \mid a \in \mathbb{Q}, a \le t \}
$$
because of the problem you mention. However, we can salvage the proof.
Let $C = \{(rs)^a \mid a \in \mathbb{Q}, a \le t \}$, and note that
$$
C \subseteq AB
$$
and moreover, for any element $r^a s^b \in AB$, $r^a s^b \le r^{\max(a,b)} s^{\max(a,b)} \in C$.

This implies that even though the two sets are not the same, they have the same supremum.
So then the proof goes through because
$$
(rs)^t = \sup C = \sup AB = \sup A \sup B = r^t s^t.
$$